# Security check for direct page access in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, authentication

I have a multi-user web application. If admin logs in, all menus are enabled. If user logs in, only limited features are allowed.

When a user's attention is needed for a task (like assigning to new project), admin sends a mail with a URL of the correct page to the user. User then can navigate to the page (without any credentials) and take the necessary action.

Now the issue is - when an admin logs into the system, triggers a mail to user and if he does not log off. User clicks on the link (in email) that opens the page in another tab (of IE/Chrome) or on the same page, user is able to see all the options that are available to the admin.

Though this is not a production centric issue, I am getting this security breach escalated in my client demos.

Additionally, the page that user is trying to reach is accessible to admins and users through appropriate menu items. This limits me to put some conditions on load of the page.

Now, how can I restrict the user to see only the options allowed to him irrespective of who already logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie or HTTP authentication will be shared by all tabs of the same browser so if you click a link when already logged in, you will remain logged in.

Possible solutions:

1. Click logout in the application before clicking the link in the email.
2. Copy and paste the link into another browser than the link was generated from (e.g. Chrome instead of Firefox).
3. Open a private tab (e.g. Incognito mode in Chrome) and paste the link in.
4. Set your default browser to a different one from where the demo was started from so when the email link is clicked it opens elsewhere.
5. Generate the URL in a separate format which contains a parameter to inform the application to expire any session and ask for reauthorisation. e.g.
   If your link is to "`www.example.com/task/1232`" the link in the email is "`www.example.com/task/1232/reauth`" which will make the application ask for the username and password before allowing access. You could expand this and have URLs in the form "`www.example.com/task/1232/user/4545`" where the app will only ask for reauthorisation if the user isn't already logged in as user ID 4545.

Answer (score 0):

If the last user logged in the application was the admin and did not log out properly, you can set a session timeout to automatically logout the user in your web.config :

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="20" cookieless="false"/>
```

For more information : [sessionState MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: We do have timeout in our application. But in the demo, I would relatively navigate quicker than this timeout period. Yet I need to prove that the application is secure.

Comment: Ok but if the user does not log out, the application cannot know which user is using it. In the demo mode, you can check if the user is the admin by requesting the admin password when accessing a private menu.